# Flutter: How do I fetch base plan and offers which is under the subscription in google play store console?

Tags: flutter

[Here is the play console screenshot]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBIpx.png)

I use the in_app_purchase library from pub.dev

I tried this to fetch a subscription but I only get the main subscription.

```
initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isPurchaseAvailble = await inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    debugPrint("App_Purchase_avalible--> $isPurchaseAvailble");
    if (isPurchaseAvailble) {
      ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
          await inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(ids.toSet());
      debugPrint("USER_PRODUCT-> ${productDetailResponse.productDetails[0]}");
      List<ProductDetails> products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
      for (ProductDetails product in products) {
        print('product:-> ${product.id}');
        print('price:-> ${product.price}');
        print('title:-> ${product.title}');
        print('description:-> ${product.description}');
        print('rawprice:-> ${product.rawPrice}');
        print('currencyCode:-> ${product.currencyCode}');
        print('currencySymbol:-> ${product.currencySymbol}');
      }
      setState(() {
        _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
      });
     
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `ids` list. FYI the ids list should contain the ids of all the subscriptions you are offering, it should be like `{id1, id2, id3}`. Also you are only print (ProductDetails[0]).

Comment: base plan ids {1,2,3}, 
I am using this ProductDetails[0] because I am only getting the parent subscription plan which product id is 1_pre, 
I am not getting any base plan.

Comment: Can you see notFoundIds property on productDetailsResponse class. https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/latest/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/ProductDetailsResponse/notFoundIDs.html

Comment: Yes, I can see notFoundIds.

Comment: What is the value of that? Can you try printing it to console?

Comment: Hi, did your issue get resolve?